# Is it possible to get django info without running it

Tags: python, django

I have a django model, the whole code is completed. but I want to access my model info. a code like this to get field names.

```
for f in myModel._meta.fields:
    print(f.get_attname())
```

is it possible to do it from an external python script without running django server?

other possible automated ways of doing this and saving results to a file are also appreciated.

###### try1

because Im using docker I ran it up. and from django container I started python shell

```
>>> from  django.conf import settings
>>> settings.configure()
>>> import models
```

it gave `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

###### try2

by @Klaus D advice in comments I tried [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/). so I created

```
users/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            _private.py
            modelInfo.py
```

structure. in `modelInfo.py` I did

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from users import views2
def savelisttxtfile(the_list, path_, type_='w', encoding="utf-8"):
    with open(path_, type_, encoding=encoding) as file_handler:
        for item in the_list:
            file_handler.write("{}\n".format(item))
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        dic=[]
        for f in views2.ChertModel._meta.fields:
            print(f.get_attname())
            dic.append(f.get_attname())
        savelisttxtfile(dic,"F:\projects\sd.txt")
```

and from another python file I tried

```
os.chdir(r'F:\projects\users\management\commands')
from subprocess import run
import sys
run([sys.executable, r'F:\projects\users\management\commands\modelInfo.py'])
```

and it returned

```
CompletedProcess(args=['C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', 'F:\projects\users\management\commands\modelInfo.py'], returncode=1)
```

and the results were not save in `sd.txt`

Comment: You could write a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: did you try to import model to other script and use it?

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @klaus D and [management command documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) I made this structure

```
users/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            _private.py
            modelInfo.py
```

and in `modelInfo.py` I did

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from users import views2
def savelisttxtfile(the_list, path_, type_='w', encoding="utf-8"):
    with open(path_, type_, encoding=encoding) as file_handler:
        for item in the_list:
            file_handler.write("{}\n".format(item))
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        dic=[]
        for f in views2.ChertModel._meta.fields:
            print(f.get_attname())
            dic.append(f.get_attname())
        savelisttxtfile(dic,"F:\projects\sd.txt")
```

and to run it I went to `manage.py location` and executed `python manage.py modelInfo` to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your "try1" it seems to be a little bit trickier to start a python shell like `python manage.py shell` than what you propose there.

Fortunately you can do this:

```
python manage.py shell < your_script.py
```

and your script will be executed as if typed directly into the "django shell". Keep in mind that you still need to import your models relative to your project, i.e. `from myapp.models import mymodel`.

Comment: I think I had tried it but now I not sure

Comment: It has to work, otherwise you have serious other problems. If you like to test it you can even execute code without a script file (in three seperate lines):
`python manage.py shell << 'EOF'`

`print("hello django world")`

`EOF`